# 2 digits after decimal point pure SQL

Tags: sql, decimal

This is my code right now:

```
SELECT 
j.job_title,
ROUND(CAST(SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id)as float)) as average_salary,
COUNT(p.id) as total_people,
ROUND(CAST(SUM(j.salary)/2 as float)) as total_salary
FROM people p
JOIN job j on p.id=j.people_id
GROUP BY j.job_title
ORDER BY average_salary desc;
```

The result on average_salary shows no decimals. Without CAST, the result shows more than 5 decimals. How do I change my code to make it show only 2 digits after decimal point?

I have tried several other code like using decimal(16,2) or numeric(16,2) instead of float, but it does not seem to work.

I want this with pure SQL. Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ROUND()` convert to `DECIMAL()`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT j.job_title,
       CAST(AVG(j.salary) as DECIMAL(16, 2)) as average_salary,
       COUNT(p.id) as total_people,
       CAST(SUM(j.salary) / 2 as DECIMAL(16, 2)) as total_salary
```

If you want to use `ROUND()` then use it *before* the conversion to decimal, not after.

Comment: I tried your option with:CAST(SUM(j.salary) / 2 as DECIMAL(16, 2)) as total_salary
But this gave me the result 0.420943E....

Comment: @tryAnroid . . . That seems really strange.  What tool are you using?  The `cast()` should really be eliminating any decimals after the second one.

Comment: I used ::FLOAT instead of CAST, worked as I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
j.job_title,
CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2),  SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id) ) as average_salary
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ROUND(SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id), 2) as average_salary
```

If you want the result as float, try:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as average_salary
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(round(SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id),2) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as average_salary
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(round(SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(j.id),2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as average_salary
```

Notice that the answer could be shown with no zero, in a case the second decimal digit is 0, depends on the database platform you use.

One of them should work.